# problem With appendChild the canvas doesn't included TypeError JS Console

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

i had an error message from the console

this is the js code

console message : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at file1.js:15**

```js
// Create the Canvas On Page

var myPageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

// Assign ID to this canvas

myPageCanvas.id = 'c';
myPageCanvas.width = 600;
myPageCanvas.height = 100;
myPageCanvas.style.display = 'block';
myPageCanvas.style.margin = '50px auto';

// Add the canvas to the Page

document.body.appendChild(myPageCanvas);

// Get Canvas information

var mycanvas = document.getElementById('c');

myContext = mycanvas.getContext('2');

// fill and style option

myContext.fillStyle = '#f00';
myContext.strokeStyle = '#00f';
myContext.lineWidth = 4;
myContext.font = '100px Arial';

// add the text

myContext.fillText('Elzero Web School', 50, 80);
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't your problem. Your context is not being recorded into the `myContext` var. To prove this you can `console.log(mycanvas)` ≈ and you will see it is actually there.

Change:

```
myContext = mycanvas.getContext('2');
```

To:

```
myContext = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: yes you're right i forgot it thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you load the script before the body.You should load the script after body tag. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>
     <body>
      <h1>Body content</h1>
     </body>
 <script>

var myPageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

// Assign ID to this canvas

myPageCanvas.id = 'c';
myPageCanvas.width = 600;
myPageCanvas.height = 100;
myPageCanvas.style.display = 'block';
myPageCanvas.style.margin = '50px auto';

// Add the canvas to the Page

document.body.appendChild(myPageCanvas);

// Get Canvas information

var mycanvas = document.getElementById('c');

myContext = mycanvas.getContext('2d');

// fill and style option

myContext.fillStyle = '#f00';
myContext.strokeStyle = '#00f';
myContext.lineWidth = 4;
myContext.font = '100px Arial';

// add the text

myContext.fillText('Elzero Web School', 50, 80);
</script>
</html>
```

Or include the js file after body load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>

     <body>
      <h1>Body content</h1>
     </body>

     <script src="path/to/file.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: i've been used the first one it works with no console message

and used the second one the content show up in the browser but i still got the console message 

so the problem just in ordering ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

test your code and the only error that I got was

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of null
```

This is because in the context you should use 2d instead of 2
after that everything works well.

The only way to reproduce your error is having an HTML file that doesn't contain a body tag or maybe you are calling the script before the body tag in the HTML structure.

This is the example working.
https://jsfiddle.net/v4e0twd5/

Comment: yes you're right i used to called JS file after the body the content show up but still got an error